# How to remove the alphabet in my case using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I wants to remove alphabet from string. In my string variable it will have the numbers with alphabet

**For example**

```
var myString = '1122D'
// I want remove the last alphabet only from the above variable

var myString = '1122Z3'
// I want remove the `Z3` from above string

var myString = '112DD2'    
// I want remove the `DD2` from above string
```

I know how to replace specific character using `.replace('','')`. But in my case it is different

Answer (score 3):

If the strings are always made up starting with numbers and you want to get the number up until the first alphabetical character, I'd recommend the use of `parseInt()` since its behaviour is exactly that it parses numeric characters in a string to a number until it encounters the first non-numeric character where it stops parsing.

```
var myNumber = parseInt(myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
myString.substr(0,myString.search('[a-zA-Z]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do like

```
myString.replace(/[^\d].*/,"");
```

Comment: This seems like the "right" way.  The other answers, while technically correct,  seem like telling a child that the way to turn on the tv is to call their sister who is upstairs, and convince her to come down and press the power button, even though they have the remote in their hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/([\d]+).+$/g` as well:

```js
var regex = /([\d]+).+$/g;

console.log(regex.exec("1122D")[1]);
regex.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(regex.exec("1122Z3")[1]);
regex.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(regex.exec("112DD2")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way -

```
myString.slice(0, myString.indexOf(myString.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)));
```